# Get bottom variable value to top of page

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<?php echo $hello; ?>

<div class="a">
    <?php $hello='Hello World!'; ?>
</div>
```

I want to get the value of bottom variable, to top of the page like this.How should I do that? Thank You!

Comment: You can't use a variable before creating it!

Comment: Yep, there i no way to make that work (with PHP and not reloading the page).

Comment: PHP executes from top of the script to the bottom. If you're echoing out a variable and then setting it later on, then you need to change your structure

Comment: luca I am going to show number of results at the top of page,but I my code is at the bottom of page with page pagination($row["total"]).I wanna get that value to top.

Comment: Then echo the values after they're filled with the results, and use CSS or similar trickery to make the echo'd content appear at the top of the screen.

Comment: Or, don't output anything, but store everything in a string until you have computed all the values, then echo the variables and output the stored data.

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="a">
    <?php $hello='Hello World!'; ?>
</div>
<?php echo $hello; ?>
```

You have to do this way if you want to go for this specific example. The reason it does not work is that you try to *echo* something that is not set yet. So you set the value of `$hello` inside the div and then you can use this variable.